# What web hosting service should i go for?

Tags: web-hosting, website-design

I want to launch a website and since i am really new at this i am not able to decide what web hosting service will be best for me. Godaddy is the name i am hearing everywhere but few people say that its not good and theymake fool of us by applying hidden charges, stealing domain name etc. So i just want to know what are the alternatives present better than godaddy. And is godaddy really good.. would you suggest me to go with godaddy ?

Comment: While questions asking for recommendations are not allowed on this site, it appears that what you are hearing about GoDaddy is a bunch of hooey (technical term). It is ridiculous on the face of it. Why, for example, would they want to steal domain names? What good is it to be known for theft to their bottom line? Don't you think they would run out of customers at some point? GoDaddy has one of the best reputations there is. There are always people who will trash talk, but ask yourself, "Is this person credible?" Likely the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godaddy has had some DNS issues going on in recent months. In general they have quite a bit of reported slow response + downtime style hiccups over time as well. I personally would not use them considering for the price there are far more stable hosts. When choosing hosting there are generally 3 things to think about:

1. Is a cheap hosting plan going to be able to run my site(s)
   effectively or do I need a VPS? Are the servers overloaded? Do they guarantee uptime and speed?
2. Are they a homebrew re-seller of a bigger host? Are they able to
   support their re-seller environment and keep me safe? Do I really need the re-seller middle-man?
3. Is there a support response-time guarantee? Is there a managed
   hosting option? Do they have an actual phone number? What time zone are they in?

Comment: I do warn against cheap. It is possible to get quality for less, but generally speaking, in order to be cheap, you have to cut corners somewhere. I used to be a web host and found that the price really does match the effort. Plus, hosting is so affordable and always has been that I would suggest going for quality and not worrying about a dollar or two.